# Facebook instance not getting created in Spring Social

Tags: spring-boot, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am trying to run a simple Spring Social application to login to Facebook account. But, Facebook instance is not created and it is showing nullpointerexception.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/fb")
public class HelloFBController {

    @Autowired
    private Facebook facebook;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloFacebook(Model model) {
        if (!facebook.isAuthorized()) {
            return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
        }

        model.addAttribute("feed", facebook.feedOperations().getFeed());

        return "hellofb";
    }
}
```

Then

```
@Configuration
public class SocialConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
        ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();

        registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
            environment.getProperty("facebook.appId"),
            environment.getProperty("facebook.appSecret")));
        return registry;
    }

    @Inject
    private Environment environment;
}
```

Then application.properties file

```
spring.social.facebook.appId=XXXXXXXXXXXX
spring.social.facebook.appSecret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Then pom.xml is

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Whether I am missing something. When I run this application using Spring Boot, I am getting the exception in Controller as bellow. I am trying to access the application at localhost:8080/fb

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at $Proxy42.isAuthorized(Unknown Source)
    at net.javabeat.spring.social.web.HelloFBController.helloFacebook(HelloFBController.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvok
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the facebook dependency, see below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Follow link below for more information:

[Accessing Facebook Data](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/)

Comment: No. I have that as spring boot dependency

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this project in a Git repository somewhere that I could try without having to recreate the example from the blog entry you pulled it from?

I also notice that your Maven dependencies are reference Spring Boot starters for Spring Social Facebook, but that you are explicitly configuring the connection factory locator (and nothing else). Consequently, if you are using Spring Boot, then your explicit configuration is probably disabled auto-configuration provided by Spring Boot. Delete SocialConfig and see what happens.

Comment: No. I don't have that in git

Comment: Is there any bug in 1.2.5 of Spring boot. It's not working after all the options I have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code for a workaround to make it working. At this time facebook is not connnected or injected so it is getting NPE:

```
try {
            if (!facebook.isAuthorized()) {
                return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
        }
```

Also, you may have to add spring.social.auto_connection_views=true if you are not using custom view.